# angularjs display index number for nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, nested

I have a nested array as shown below:
***EDIT ARRAY*

```
nested = {
  "_id": 24,
  "itemId": 15,
  "testGroups": [
    {
      "TestGroupName": null,
      "testGroup": [
        {
          "TestName": "ddasdasd",
          "TestType": 1,
                "testGroup": []
        },
        {
          "TestName": "dsadasddasd",
          "TestType": 2,
                   "testGroup": []
        },
        {
          "TestName": "adsdasd",
          "TestType": 0,
                    "testGroup": [
            {
              "TestGroupName": "dasdasd",
              "testGroup": [
                {
                  "TestName": "dasdasd",
                  "TestType": 1,
                                    "testGroup": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "TestGroupName": "dasdasd",
              "testGroup": [
                {
                  "TestName": "dasdasd",
                  "TestType": 2,
               "testGroup": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "TestName": "dasdasddasd",
          "TestType": 2,
          "testGroup": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to display the index and subindex as **1.1 , 1.2, 1.2.1 ....** for `TestName`

I've tried with a combination of `$parent.$index` and `$index` but it's not working for subitems as it displays 0 as index.

Comment: your json is invalid. please provide valid and formated json

Comment: Provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Assing index to a variable using `ng-init`

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in arr" ng-init="parentIndex = $index" >
    <div ng-repeat="subitem in item.subitems" ng-init="chilIndex = $index">
    {{parentIndex}}.{{chilIndex}}
     </div>
 </div>
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.arr = [  
   {  
      item:"",
      subitems:[  
         {  
            item:"",
            subitems:[  
               {  
                  item:"",
                  subitems:[  
                     {  
                        item:"",
                        subitems:[  

                        ]
                     },
                     {  
                        item:"",
                        subitems:[  

                        ]
                     }

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            item:"",
            subitems:[  

            ]
         }

      ]
   },
   {  
      item:"",
      subitems:[  
         {  
            item:"",
            subitems:[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            item:"",
            subitems:[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in arr" ng-init="parentIndex = $index" >
    <div ng-repeat="subitem in item.subitems" ng-init="chilIndex = $index">
    {{parentIndex}}.{{chilIndex}}
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response , i am actually using angular-ui-tree component and the level is not defined how deep it indexing will go , any ideas on that??